# Laptop - always on

Tags: laptop, bios, power, power-management

I would like to make my laptop always on, even after power loss.

On PC it's simple. I used to enter the BIOS, then `Power Management Setup` and set the option `Restore on AC/Power loss` to `Enable`. Unfortunately I don't have this option in my laptop (HP 6715s).

Is there any way to keep my laptop on all the time, especially on it automatically after power outage?

Comment: If you need to turn the laptop on after a power outage, then you have already failed in keeping it on *all the time*. :D

Answer (score 1):

If your BIOS doesnt support power after loss, you will have to use a [UPS](https://www.amazon.com/Computer-Uninterruptible-Power-Supply-Units/b?ie=UTF8&node=764572) to keep the laptop powered through an outtage.

It cant hurt to check if there a BIOS update for your laptop.  There is always that slim chance they added that feature.

I just did some googling.  Check to see if there is a "Restore previous state."  Thats the verbage HP uses.

Comment: Note: laptop battery is its primary UPS. If outages are not too long, sole battery may suffice.

Answer (score -1):

It's not a BIOS change, but Windows has the Power Options.

Use the below walk though, and you should be able to change things to "Always On" or to set power off/sleep mode/hibernate to "Never".

> https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/9090/learning-windows-7-manage-power-settings/

Basically, you're looking for Power Options either in the Start menu Search, or in the Control Panel.  Poking around in there should give you an idea of what to change.

Mac's have a similar group of setting called Energy Saver.

> https://is.oregonstate.edu/cn/tech-tips-using-cn/power-management/how-do-i-change-power-settings-my-apple-computer

Basically, you go to the Apple menu, click on System Preferences, then click on Energy Saver.  Most of those options are directly on the main screen.

IDK if Linux/Unix have the same options, but I would have to assume so.  There are too many flavors to try and list them, so Google is your friend, if you need it.

The OS, regardless of your settings, may put your laptop to sleep or shut down if your battery gets below 5%.  That's to save it from having file corruption issues when you restart.  You usually don't have a choice there.

Comment: He wants the laptop to power on after a power loss, no OS setting in will accomplish this, since there is no power.

Comment: @Keltari, as far as I read it, there's 2 parts to this question: keeping the laptop on after power loss; and turning it back on after power is restored.  I answered the first part, but not the second.  If there isn't a BIOS setting for turning on after the power is resumed, nothing is going to answer the 2nd part.  At least, not without manual intervention.